# Python: Converting a linked list to a list using a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, linked-list, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a simple `linked list` implementation using a dictionary called child that associates a node with the following node in the linked list.

For example:

```
 a->b->c->d
```

Would be :

```
 {a:b,b:c,c:d,d:None}
```

Converting this to a normal list is trivial,

```
myList=[]
node=a
while node!=None:
    myList.append(node)
    node=child[node]
```

I'm struggling to come up with any way this would be possible with a list comprehension. Is there no way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Summary:** List comprehensions are designed around for-loops rather than while-loops, so this isn't a good fit.

**What would be needed:** The for-loop requires an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) for input.

**Alternative 1:** This could work with a list comprehension, but that would entail shifting the work into a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) (which likely isn't what you were hoping for):

```
>>> child = {'a':'b', 'b': 'c', 'c': 'd', 'd': None}
>>> def ll_iterator(node):
        while node != None:
            yield node
            node = child[node]

>>> [x for x in ll_iterator('a')]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

**Alternative 2:** Besides generators, another way to make an iterator is to use the two argument form of [iter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter).  For that to work, you would need a stateful, zero-argument function that emitted successive linked list nodes:

```
>>> child = {'a':'b', 'b': 'c', 'c': 'd', 'd': None}
>>> def next_ll(state=['a']):
        value = state[0]
        if value is not None:
            state[0] = child[value]
            return value

>>> [x for x in iter(next_ll, None)]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

**Assessment:** Both of these alternatives are a bit gross, so you're better-off without the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension).  Simple, straight-forward code is the best :-)

**Footnote:** This question is a good one.  More than one person has suggested that the language add while-loop comprehensions.  If that suggestion ever came to fruition, Python 3.8's adoption of [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) would also help for your use case.